# Share Google Drive Folder with submitters of Google Form

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-forms

I have a Google Form that is used as a sign up form. This form has a question requesting emails. It uses the email validation. I have a Google Drive folder that I want everyone who signs up to be able to view. Some of these files, I want to be able to easily set it up so they can edit it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

This could be done by using [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start).

## Instructions

1. Open the form editor
2. Click More (the three dots buttons) > Script editor...
3. Add the script included below
4. Click on Resourses > Current project triggers
5. Click on Add a new trigger
6. Set the parameters as shown in the following snapshot:

[image: Current project's triggers]

7. Click save.

## Script

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // Set custom parameters (change this)
  var emailQuestionTitle = 'Email';
  var folderId = '0B5xqUTHHK_n6d3pWc2l5dVBWZ1k';
  
  // Get the email
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var i = 0;
  try {
    while(itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle() != emailQuestionTitle){
      i++;    
    }
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log(emailQuestionTitle + ' not found');
  }
  var emailAddress = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
  
  // Share the folder
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  folder.addEditor(emailAddress);
}
```