# Group file responses from Google Forms into individual folders per submission

Tags: google-drive, google-forms

For a given sample form `My Form` and a file `TheFile.pdf`, file uploads on Google Forms are uploaded like this:

**My Form (File Responses) > Question 1 to upload file (File Responses) > TheFile.pdf**

Is it possible to make it so that the form groups all files pertaining to one entry together or under one folder like this?:

**My Form (File Responses) > Submitter Email > Question 1 to upload file (File Responses) > TheFile.pdf**

OR

**My Form (File Responses) > Question 1 to upload file (File Responses) > Submitter Email > Question 1 (File Responses) > TheFile.pdf**

Answer (score 1):

It's not a build-in function but we could use [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start) onSubmit event to trigger a script to move files or to do many other things. For an example of things that could be done this way, see my [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/98784/88163) to [Share Google Drive Folder with submitters of Google Form](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/98578/88163)

Answer (score -1):

If it is not too late... and if the name of the folder is not important to you - only the location of it:
Let Google create its upload folder  named as: Folder (Form name)/Subfolder (upload field name).

Then when this is created in the root of your drive .. just move it to your desired location. New uploads will go there where you moved the folder.